# Laravel Multi Lang Website redirects to Server Error 500 for bots

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-500

I created a Laravel App which is Multi Language in englisch and german.

So I have 'my-domain.com/en' and 'my-domain.com/de' 
If no language segment was set and somebody is directly visiting my-domain.com I will detect the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` and set it if its in my predefines locales.

My Fallback Language is german.
For normal users its working great but the most onpage SEO Tools to analyze my website will throw and error when I type in 'my-domain.com' and they will return Error 500

So I used http://redirectcheck.com/ to see whats going on when a bot will visit my site and it will also return: `HTTP/2 500`

**Language.php middleware Code:**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //All predefined Languages [Array]
        $locales = config('app.locales');

        // Check if the first segment matches a language code
        if (!array_key_exists($request->segment(1), $locales)) {

            //Detect Browser Lang
            $detectedLang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

            // Store segments in array
            $segments = $request->segments();

            if(array_key_exists($detectedLang, $locales)) {
                $segments = Arr::prepend($segments, $detectedLang);
            }else {
                $segments = Arr::prepend($segments, config('app.fallback_locale'));
            }
            // Redirect to the correct url
            return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
        }
        // The request already contains the language code
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: What if request doesn't have `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header?

Comment: When I replace the second If statement with ```if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) && array_key_exists($detectedLang, $locales)) {```

I will get the same Error 500

Comment: Look at your server logs, what are saying?

Comment: If finally fixed it because of your help!
The problem was that the ```HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE```does not exist. And I set the variable which contains the ```HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE``` Header which not exist. I added ```isset()``` there and the previous ```isset()``` check and everything works perfectly like expected.

Thank you very much!